# What is the best way to implement a server database to be accessed from mobile apps (ios, android)?

Tags: mysql, ios, database, sqlite, mobile

I'm creating a mobile app to access journal articles. 
They are organized by Volume -> Issue -> Section -> Article. This means that I will have 13 * 4 * 10 * 3 = 1560 articles. What is a good way to implement a database to host these articles (including their images, resources, etc) on a web server? Each article is currently marked up in HTML. I believe this is nice, because in my apps I will display the content in a web view. However, I'll need to query the articles for search functions, saving locally to the device, etc.

I'd prefer it to be open source, and as I'm new to databases (but fairly proficient in app development), I'd appreciate if you could point me toward the best way of learning.

Comment: there are most likely multiple ways to do what you are trying to do. If you are trying to set up a mysql server they are fairly easy to setup, and im sure there are many tutorials out there. I would also recommend [phpmyadmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php), a open source web admin interface for mysql.

Comment: Also, sometimes a webview isn't the answer to everything. It might be better to just get the text of the articles and then the images and format it all pretty in a custom view.

Comment: I suppose I figured this was easiest because all of the text is marked up properly, including references to footnotes at the bottom of the articles.

Comment: whats easiest isn't always whats best :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you are looking for advice concerning the structure but this might help you as an approach for further thinking:

- create a table in which you write all the data
- You have one column with a unique ID for each article
- one column for each field of Volume, issue etc.
- Then you have one column that contains a huge string in which you put the html data as a string. (There might be a better way especially concerning a search function)
- You can also save it as a BLOB but this makes indexing a lot harder.
- I would probably save the resources separated from the database. Then you just name them after the article id. For example resource number 10 in article 5 would be 5.10.pdf or whatever format. This depends on your html format of course. And whether you want to rename all your files (might be A LOT of work for 1500 articles)